Parse dataframe into list of subinterval dataframes for processing
I have a dataframe, esu_tos:
Time                    TickType    Price   Size
2023-08-13 15:10:46.166 1           4487.25 1
2023-08-13 15:10:47.375 1           4487    1
2023-08-13 15:10:54.656 1           4487.25 2
2023-08-13 15:10:57.627 1           4487    1
2023-08-13 15:10:57.628 1           4487    1
2023-08-13 15:10:57.628 1           4487    1
2023-08-13 15:11:00.759 1           4487.25 1
2023-08-13 15:11:00.759 1           4487    3
2023-08-13 15:11:01.415 1           4487    3
2023-08-13 15:11:01.416 1           4487    1

That I'd like to parse into sub-intervals like below.  Is there a better way to do this aside from the loop?
interval = '5s' # 1min / 30s / 10s / 5s
st = datetime(2023,8,13,15,10)
end = datetime(2023,8,14,14,1)

rng = pd.date_range(st, end, freq = interval, inclusive='both')


d = []
d_t = []
for i, k in enumerate(rng):   
    try: 
        a = esu_tos[(esu_tos.Time >= k) & (esu_tos.Time < rng[i+1])]
        
    except:
        a = esu_tos[(esu_tos.Time >= k) & (esu_tos.Time <= end)]

    d.append(a)   
    d_t.append(k)

Looking specifically to return a list or other object which will allow me to access the data aggregated to each interval -- not simply as pd.Grouper or groupby object.
For instance, the included code creates a list of dataframes, which I'm subsequently able to access process individually.

IIUC, you can use DatFrame.groupby + pd.Grouper (and then you can add dataframes to list or datastructure...):
for g in esu_tos.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Time", freq="5s")):
    print(g[0])
    print(g[1])
    print("-" * 80)

Prints:
2023-08-13 15:10:45
                     Time  TickType    Price  Size
0 2023-08-13 15:10:46.166         1  4487.25     1
1 2023-08-13 15:10:47.375         1  4487.00     1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-13 15:10:50
                     Time  TickType    Price  Size
2 2023-08-13 15:10:54.656         1  4487.25     2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-13 15:10:55
                     Time  TickType   Price  Size
3 2023-08-13 15:10:57.627         1  4487.0     1
4 2023-08-13 15:10:57.628         1  4487.0     1
5 2023-08-13 15:10:57.628         1  4487.0     1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-13 15:11:00
                     Time  TickType    Price  Size
6 2023-08-13 15:11:00.759         1  4487.25     1
7 2023-08-13 15:11:00.759         1  4487.00     3
8 2023-08-13 15:11:01.415         1  4487.00     3
9 2023-08-13 15:11:01.416         1  4487.00     1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

